# Automotive relay circuit

Tags: voltage, power, current, relay, automotive

I have a relay in my car that is constantly fed power through a fuse to terminal 30 and terminal 86, the wiring diagram shows the ignition does not need to be on. When I check positions 30 and 86 with the relay out, they have power. The relay is grounded by the  computer to terminal 85 when the ignition is turned on and as I understand it should close the relay 30 to 87. It isn't doing that. With the ignition off, and testing for continuity I put a voltmeter on the wire coming from 85 to the computer, with the relay in, it is showing 12v, nothing with the relay out, it is supposed to be a ground. If I disconnect the negative terminal from the battery and pull the relay out to check again, I get voltage at 87 as well as 30 and 86. The voltage at 87 is not present when the negative battery terminal is attached. I can't understand how position 87 can have power with the negative battery terminal disconnected or why power is going into 85 when the relay is in. Thanks in advance if you have any ideas.  Relay 229 in this picture https://saabwisonline.com/images/9440/img-ff/ffpv0406.jpg

Comment: Hi Phillip, can you draw a diagram of what you have (as you understand it)?

Comment: To check if "it is supposed to be a ground" is true, connect the red voltmeter probe to 12 V and the black probe to 85. If it is ground, the voltmeter will show 12 V. But you don't need this test if the relay coil is OK (it will serve as a *pull-up* resistor). A tip: Use a test lamp.

Comment: With a 10M DMM you are likely getting a false reading from gnd leakage and stored voltages in caps to frame.  It’s the ECU main relay.